# How do I preselect a vue-multiselect option when options is an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, preset, vue-multiselect

I want to pre-select a particular value in a select drop-down generated by `vue-multiselect`.
I can get this to work fine if I have a simple array of strings like the following:

```
['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3']
```

However, when I use an array of objects, I can't get this to work. For example, if I have the following:

```
<v-multiselect :options="[{id: 1, name: 'Test 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Test 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Test 3'}]"
               label="name"
               track-by="id"
               v-model="test">
</v-multiselect>
```

No matter what I set the `test` data property that v-model is connected to, it won't preselect the value. I've tried `1`, `2`, `3`, `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` for `test` when `track-by` is `id` and `'Test 1'`, etc. when `track-by` is `name` but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here? I looked at the docs at https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-single-select-object, but they don't seem to provide an example when you want to preset a value for an array of objects for the options. Googling has also not returned what I'm looking for.

On a related topic, once I get this working, what would I have to change to select multiple values for when I set the component to `multiple`? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### `track-by` usage

The docs indicate that `track-by` is *"Used to compare objects. **Only use if options are objects.**"*

That is, it specifies the object key to use when comparing the object values in `options`. The docs should actually state that `track-by` is **required when the options are objects** because `<vue-multiselect>` uses `track-by` [to determine which options in the dropdown are selected](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/blob/c4924e2/src/multiselectMixin.js#L459-L462) and [to properly remove a selected option from a multiselect](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/blob/c4924e2/src/multiselectMixin.js#L607-L609).

Without `track-by`, you'd see two buggy behaviors for object-options: (1) the user would be able to re-select already selected options, and (2) attempting to remove selected options would instead cause all options to be re-inserted.

### Setting initial values

`<vue-multiselect>` doesn't support automatically translating a value array, but you could easily do that from the parent component.

1. Create a local data property to specify `track-by` and initial multiselect values (e.g., named `trackBy` and `initialValues`, respectively):

   ```
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         //...
         trackBy: 'id',
         initialValues: [2, 5],
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Bind `<vue-multiselect>.track-by` to `this.trackBy` and `<vue-multiselect>.v-model` to `this.value`:

   ```
   <vue-multiselect :track-by="trackBy" v-model="value">
   ```
3. Create a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `this.initialValues` that maps those values into an object array based on `this.trackBy`, setting `this.value` to the result:

   ```
   export default {
     watch: {
       initialValues: {
         immediate: true,
         handler(values) {
           this.value = this.options.filter(x => values.includes(x[this.trackBy]));
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

```js
Vue.component('v-multiselect', window.VueMultiselect.default);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      trackBy: 'id',
      initialValues: [5,2],
      value: null,
      options: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    initialValues: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(values) {
        this.value = this.options.filter(x => values.includes(x[this.trackBy]));
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <v-multiselect :track-by="trackBy"
                 :options="options"
                 v-model="value"
                 label="name"
                 multiple>
  </v-multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of that. I get it, and I'm going to have to implement something like that, but honestly, it feels like a poor-man's solution. `vue-multiselect` should automatically handle this for you when you specify `track-id`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug.  The workaround is to use an actual reference to the `object`

```js
Vue.component('v-multiselect', window.VueMultiselect.default);
let testOptions=[{id: 1, name: 'Test 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Test 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Test 3'}]
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      test: testOptions[1], // <- use an object ref here!
      testOptions
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Steven. I've tried setting all of the following for `test` in my returned `data` object, and none of them work: `1`, `'1'`, `[1]`, `['1']`, `{ id: 1 }`, `{ id: '1' }`. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. I set `:options="testOptions"` in the component and then set the following property in the `data` object: `[{id: 1, name: 'Test 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Test 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Test 3'}]`. Tried setting `test` to all the various possibilities again, but nothing worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: Here ya go: https://codepen.io/HartleySan/pen/NomLqN?editors=1111. The commented-in code doesn't work, but if you switch that out with the commented out HTML and JS, then it pre-selects the `Test 1` value. Not a clue.

Comment: Steven, you're right, that does work. Not a great workaround though for two reasons: 1) I'm not going to readily have the selected object handy. Usually I'll have the ID, which I wanted to select the object from; and 2) If you do that, you don't even need the `track-by` attribute, in which case, what is that attribute for? Is it buggy? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but it seems like the library is buggy. If you set `track-by="id"`, then I would think that you should be able to set `test: 1` and be good to go. I wonder if I should submit a bug report on this.

Comment: Its surely a bug.  I started using `vuetify` after dealing with this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found out is sending the whole object from BE, so it gets pre-selected. If you send the same object from BE will get pre-selected. But I don't know if your options are hard coded on FE or they are coming from a database or something. I had the same issue but my values were coming from my database, so it was easy to reproduce the object

Answer (score 0):

In your question just :object="true" is missing actually they didn't know that it is of type string or object when we pass this it knows yes it is object and i need label="name" from v-model="test" and picks it and shows it as a preselected

Comment: I had a same issue and i fixed it in this way

Comment: You are aware that you can [edit] your posts for adding information, aren't you? You could take the opportunity to try more along [answer].